# SQL 'SELECT' Statement with Calculated Column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm developing an IT Support Management database. The following SQL query involves two tables. The 'devices' table contains all the PCs owned by a company, and the 'services' table is a list of every service performed on devices (ie. each device can have multiple services).

I want this query to retrieve the `entire 'devices' table`, but include an extra column that shows the `total` number of `services` for each `device`.

The following statement I've come up with is probably far from correct. For every row, it returns a count of the total number of records in the `'services'` table (ie. same number on each row) rather than grouping/filtering to each device.

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT Count(services.id)
        FROM   dbo.services
               LEFT JOIN devices
                      ON services.assetID = devices.assetID
        GROUP  BY devices.assetID) AS TotalServices
FROM   dbo.devices
```

What approach should I be using to achieve this? Thanks in advance for any guidance or assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the rows from `devices` table then `dbo.devices` should be present in left side of `Left outer Join`.

Remove the `subquery` and make it as `Left outer join` then count the number of service per `assetID`.  Try this.

```
SELECT devices.assetID,
       TotalServices=Count(services.id)
FROM   dbo.devices
       LEFT JOIN dbo.services
              ON services.assetID = devices.assetID
GROUP  BY devices.assetID
```

Comment: Perfect! Does exactly what I needed it to. That makes perfect sense. Thanks for the prompt reply - really appreciate it.